How to resize part of object/ figure
I have a model of an amplifier bass/treble volume knob that I want to resize and 3D-print. It consists of a hollow cylinder and inside of it, in its center, is a socket which connects it to the amplifier.
Here's a picture of how it looks like:
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4721627
I wonder how I can resize the outer cylinder, without simultaneously resizing the inner socket? How can I select the outer cylinder, without simultaneously selecting the inner socket?
Thank you for any help you can offer

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Go to edit mode, press NumPad 1 to set front orthographic view (press NumPad 5 if perspective), go to Wireframe mode (Z), press B to box select all bottom vertices.

Then Press Ctrl NumPad +   twice, to expand the selection.
Now you can press S, Shift Z, move the mouse, click to confirm (Scale uniformly except on Z axis).
